# DataRow Copy Values from another DataRow with Extra Column

Tags: c#, datarow

I have a DataRow like {"Foo", "Bar"} in a corresponding DataTable with 2 string columns.  I want to **copy** this row to a new DataTable, which has **3** string columns, the 0th of which is a new value that I want to pass-in.  So the resulting row should look like {"My", "Foo", "Bar"}.

Rinse, repeat.  Another copy operation would go like {"Bob", "Smith"} => {"My", "Bob", "Smith"}.

I tried using the DataRow.ItemArray in an Array.Copy(), and myDataRow.ItemArray.CopyTo(otherDataRow.ItemArray) as well.  Then I read that that doesn't work because the ItemArray is kinda Read-Only despite the intellisense telling you otherwise.

And of course I can write my own loop to copy the values column-by-column, but.. **Why** is this not built into the libraries or something?

Sample-code:

```
DataTable dtDestination = new DataTable();
DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();

dtSource.Columns.Add("Str1");
dtSource.Columns.Add("Str2");

dtDestination.Columns.Add("Str0");
dtDestination.Columns.Add("Str1");
dtDestination.Columns.Add("Str2");

dtSource.Rows.Add("Foo", "Bar");
dtSource.Rows.Add("Bob", "Smith");

foreach (DataRow drSrc in dtSource.Rows)
{
    DataRow drNew = dtDestination.NewRow();
    drNew["Str0"] = "My";

    //this doesn't work
    Array.Copy(drSrc.ItemArray, 0, drNew.ItemArray, 1, drSrc.ItemArray.Length);

    //this doesn't work either
    drSrc.ItemArray.CopyTo(drNew.ItemArray, 1);

    //I want to add the "new row" to my destination table,
    //*WITH* the contents from the source-row plus the "My" value in the 0th column!
    dtDestination.Rows.Add(drNew);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with iterating?  `drNew[1] = drSrc[0]; drNew[2] = drSrc[1]`

Comment: That's my point... I can easily do that with a loop, fine.  I'm asking why isn't this kind of thing built in to the framework, or at least to some library that one could just call upon.

Comment: Because its straight forward and easy to do. Will perform better than array copying for example.

Comment: @Zer0 How would it perform better?  It's still O(N), where N = size of array = # of columns in row.  But I do see your point, it's trivial to implement oneself -- just seems silly to not have a `DataRow.CopyValuesFrom(otherDataRow, startingIndex)` or something.

Comment: Because the `ItemArray` is already created when you call `NewRow`.  It's adding memory pressure producing more garbage for the GC.  The accepted answer is creating 2 arrays per row.  As for your example, what if I wanted to copy columns 1, 2 and 4?  It's just too specific a use case and iterating is very simple to do.  There's no real problem to solve here.

Comment: @Zer0 I think we're on the same page -- I _don't want to use ItemArray_ either.  I'm working on a method that simply copies (by *reference*, since all the row's items are objects) one row's values to another, and it seems to me like something that could be easily built-in.

Comment: Use an extension method.  I could write up your `DataRow.CopyValuesFrom` if that helps.  I would just avoid the added memory pressure.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the .ItemArray values without SetValue
But you can Set the ItemArray itself

```
        DataTable dtDestination = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();

        dtSource.Columns.Add("Str1");
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Str2");

        dtDestination.Columns.Add("Str0");
        dtDestination.Columns.Add("Str1");
        dtDestination.Columns.Add("Str2");

        dtSource.Rows.Add("Foo", "Bar");
        dtSource.Rows.Add("Bob", "Smith");

        foreach (DataRow drSrc in dtSource.Rows)
        {
            DataRow drNew = dtDestination.NewRow();
            var array = new object[drSrc.ItemArray.Length];
            array[0] = "My";
            Array.Copy(drSrc.ItemArray, 0, array, 1, drSrc.ItemArray.Length);
            drNew.ItemArray = array;
            dtDestination.Rows.Add(drNew);
        }
```

And you should add Testvalues to the Source, not Destination Table...

Comment: Nice answer!  Thanks for the catch on putting test-values in dtDestination; I've edited my question to put them in the dtSource.

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method:

```
public static void CopyValuesFrom(this DataRow me, DataRow copyFrom, int insertIndex = 0, int copyIndex = 0, int count = 0)
{
    if (count == 0)
        count = Math.Min(copyFrom.ItemArray.Length - copyIndex, me.ItemArray.Length - insertIndex);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        me[insertIndex + i] = copyFrom[copyIndex + i];
}
```

Do the copy:

```
drNew.CopyValuesFrom(drSrc, 1);
```

Comment: I wrote a mini-library (though I may be misusing that term), if you'd like to review my code at let me know what you think -- https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/AGswyE

Comment: @NateJ - It's similar to my answer but less flexible.  Few things.  They aren't extension methods and you can't specify your own count to copy.  Personally, if you want to double check inputs I would throw more specific exceptions (like `InvalidOperationException`).  In that case I'd also check for null and throw `ArgumentNullException`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a straightfoward method to do that, just use ImportRow method and additionally after this supply value of additional column